# How to display returned JSON in jQuery Mobile pop up

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

First of all, I'm not sure which is the correct widget here, popup or dialog. I'm going with pop up for now. I have a form, when submitted I want to display the results in a pop up. Validation and JSON stuff here:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
        //serializeObject function stuff
    };

    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $('#myForm').validate({
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.is('select')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parents('div.ui-select'));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parents('div.ui-input-text'));  // default placement
                    }
                },
                    errorElement: 'em',
                    submitHandler: function(form){
                    var wrapper = {};
                    var location = {};
                    wrapper.location = $("#newLocation").serializeObject();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: $(form).attr('method'),
                        url: 'server' + 'service' + '/' + 'servicecall',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        data: JSON.stringify(wrapper),
                        clearform: true,
//****Here is where the fun starts**
                        success: function(msg) {
                                var ID = msg.location.id;
                                //other element ID's...
                                //pop up vars
                                var $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
                                    dismissable: true,
                                    theme: "d",
                                    overlayTheme: "a",
                                    transition: "pop"
                                }).on("popupafterclose", function () {
                                    $(this).remove;
                                });
                                if(msg.success){
                                    $('#newLocation').slideUp('fast');
                                    $popUp.popup('open').append(ID);
                                 }
                            },
                            error: function(msg) {
                                $popUp.popup('open').append('Error');
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    },
                    rules: {
                        //rules
                    },
                    messages: {
                       //messages
                    }
                });
            });
```

I need to create the pop up dynamically and append some of the returned data. I can append the returned data to a hidden div/table that is shown upon success, but want to attempt this with a dynamically created popup (or dialog if that is best). I just can't get it to create the popup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the popup outside the ajax section so it can be used by all segments
(success, error etc.)

```
popup = '<div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissable="true" data-transition="pop"></div>';

$.mobile.activePage.append( popup ).trigger( "pagecreate" );

$( document ).on( "popupafterclose", ".ui-popup", function() {
    $( this ).remove();
});
```

And then you can use it

```
success: function(msg) {
     var ID = msg.location.id;
     //other element ID's...
     if(msg.success){
        $("#popup").popup('open').append(ID);
     }
},
error: function(msg) {
      $("#popup").popup('open').append('Error');
}
```

I believe something like this would work.

**UPDATE 1**
I took the above from the documents. Yours could work too, but you don't attach it in the DOM. Yes you create an HTML element (`<div/>`) but you don't attach it to the DOM. Maybe attaching it to active page as above could fix yours.

**UPDATE 2**
I tried to fix some other faults, like the one that you use the popup in the `error:` but you create the popup only in `success:`

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: I will, just need to test.

Comment: Oh sorry then :P . I thought you had. Have fun

Comment: The code works as expected, thank you! Any feeling on popup vs dialog?

Comment: It's more about aesthetics I guess. You should try it on a mobile device and ask someone that is not a programmer. That's what I do. But I think for this in particular a dialog makes a little bit more sense to me.

Comment: Looks like basically the same set up for dialog, just replacing 'popup' with 'dialog' - HMMM not quite get this error " Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open' "

Comment: Wow, I never saw the last comment. Sorry. Even if it's too late... you are trying to call a methof of an element that hasn't been initialized by jqm. In your case you are trying to open the dialog when jqm hasn't finished initializing (or never even started, depending on your code).